# Reorder android linear layout at runtime?

Tags: android, layout

I have a horizontal linear layout as my root element in my layout file. The linear layout contains two relative layouts which each have several child elements. How can i swap the position of these two relative layouts?

I tried

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.horizontalLayout);
RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.panelLayout);
RelativeLayout rl2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.boardLayout);
vg.removeAllViews();
vg.addView(rl2);
vg.addView(rl1);
```

I also tried

```
vg.removeView(rl2);
vg.addView(rl2, 0);
```

Both result in the second relative layout (rl2) taking up the entire width. I can post my xml file if needed but it's pretty long. Also both relative layouts have height=match_parent and width=wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <com.mydomain.tetrisv2.PreviewGridView
        android:id="@+id/previewGridView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/previewGridView1"
        android:text="Score: 0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/pausestr"
        android:onClick="btnPause_Click" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPaused"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/pausedstr"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/previewGridView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="@string/savestr"
        android:onClick="btnSave_Click" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/boardLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mydomain.tetrisv2.GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/downarrow"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="btnDrop_Click" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/leftarrow"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="btnLeft_Click" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="btnRight_Click" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to help you determine where you are going wrong with your approach. Without the layout files, it will be very difficult for anyone to help you. Your code seems fine.

Comment: thought i described my layout file pretty well atleast the important part but i guess you're right ill post the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a flavor of `addView()` that takes a `LayoutParams` as the second value, and supply a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` that matches the values you are currently setting in your XML ("height=match_parent and width=wrap_content").

Comment: @user1938939: Hmmmm... well, I'm back to the Hierarchy View recommendation, as it should help identify what isn't getting the right `LayoutParams` values.

Comment: Looking into it now. very interesting had no idea this tool existed, im pretty new to android